# How to check if a string matches a format in java?

Tags: java, string, format

```
public static String[] positionQuery(int dim, Scanner test_in) {
Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Provide origin and destination coordinates.");
        System.out.println("Enter two positions between A1-H8:");
        String s = stdin.nextLine();
        String coordinates [] = s.split(" ");
        String origin = coordinates[0];
        String dest = coordinates[1];
```

Here is my code, I am getting two strings from the scanner and I want to check if the positions have the correct format of capital letter and integer. I looked at the .matches() method but didn't quite get how to do it with this pattern: **A1-H8**

The strings are like E6, B4, F1, A8... the pattern is capital letter-integer.

Cheers!

Comment: What have you tried?  Are you trying to use regex, if so what regex are you trying with? If you can do with regex, have your tried using simple char comparison ?

Comment: How is the simple char comparison? All I can think of is to convert the string origin and dest into arrays of char and then using the for loop if the first element of that array is one of {A.....letter that is determined by the dim entry} and then use for loop for the second element to see if it is an integer from 1 until dim. But it doesn't seem that simple. So I would like to know if there is a simpler way of checking the pattern!

Comment: see the answer below from @jeremy-kahan for ideas

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are only working with single-digit numbers and passing in a 2 character String to test (after splitting), if the string is s, this expression should do:

```
(s.length()==2) && Character.isLetter(s.charAt(0)) && Character.isDigit(s.charAt(1))
```

REVISION: as Andreas pointed out in a comment, when fed Ψ1, the above evaluates to true (isUpperCase also is no use fixing it, because that Phi is upper case).

I like the below less, but it avoids the indicated issue:

```
(s.length()==2) && ("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".indexOf(s.charAt(0))>-1) && Character.isDigit(s.charAt(1))
```

I am going along with the requirement from the original problem and clarified in comments that the letter be upper case.

Revision 2: The fix was unnecessarily ugly. Nicer is:

```
(s.length()==2) && (s.charAt(0)>='A') && (s.charAt(0)<='Z')&& Character.isDigit(s.charAt(1))
```

Comment: ohh I get it now!

Comment: Is it case sensitive? To be correct format the letter has to be uppercase.

Comment: @KaleJoe - why don't you research? The [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isUpperCase(char)) has just what you want

Comment: That pointer from @ScaryWombat will get you what you need. I might err on the side of if someone says b7, convert it to B7 rather than treating it as invalid. And no, it's not case sensitive.

Comment: `Character.isLetter` would allow letters like `Ψ` (['GREEK CAPITAL LETTER PSI' (U+03A8)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/03a8/index.htm)), so that's not a good solution when OP only seems to want to match `A`-`H`. --- `Character.isDigit` would allow digits like `௫` (['TAMIL DIGIT FIVE' (U+0BEB)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0beb/index.htm)).

Comment: @Andreas, good catch. I will update.

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.Scanner;

public class PatternCheck {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = scan.nextLine();
    scan.close();
    String RegexPattern = "^[A-Z][0-9]$";// Change the pattern as per your
                                            // requirement
    String sAr[] = s.split("-");

    for (int i = 0; i < sAr.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(sAr[i].matches(RegexPattern));
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

If you do not have requirement of ordering then regex `[A-H][1-8]-[A-H][1-8]` can help (as a Java string: `"[A-H][1-8]-[A-H][1-8]"`)

Example: `A1-H8` , `H4-G7` , `C8-A1`

You can test it out here: https://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Comment: Why are you escaping the `-`?

Comment: Do you know if we escape `-`, it will result in wrong solution? As per specs, `-` is used to specify range (e.g. `[a-z]`) in square brackets. However specs does not clarify if `-` was used in there as valid character (e.g. `[(--]`), would it be required to be escaped or not though I've seen it working with and without escaping. So extending the fact about `-` being special, I was not sure if used outside square brackets if it requires escaping or not.

Comment: A `-` dash is only special in a place where it can have special meaning, so it is not special: 1) Outside a `[...]` character class. 2) `[-abc]` At start of character class. 3) `[abc-]` At end of character class. 4) `[a-c-e]` After a range (first `-` is range delimiter, second `-` is not, i.e. that matches `abce-` but not `d`).

Comment: Thanks @Andreas for further explaination, I have updated solution accordingly. Although not yet sure if having it escaped will result in wrong behavior or not.

Comment: Escaping it would not result in wrong behavior, but it's superfluous, and excessive escaping makes the regex unweildy to us mere humans, especially once you double them in a Java string literal.